# kubernetes: set environment variable as integer

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables

I want to set Kubernetes Deployment env with integer value, but I have to quote the value for Kubernetes Deployment to accept it. This makes the env value a string and is causing a `TypeError` in the app.

Is there any workaround to set integer or float value to env?

Comment: All environment variables are strings.

Comment: Just parseInt() or something similar in your app.

Comment: Yes thats what I am doing now, handling type conversion in app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it was answered in comment, however I'll add references from official kubernetes documentation.

`env` field uses `EnvVar array`. Based on **EnvVar v1 core** API group, `name` and `value` should be only strings.
Please see [EnvVar v1 core](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#envvar-v1-core)

And here is an official example to see how variables are set:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dependent-envars-demo
spec:
  containers:
    - name: dependent-envars-demo
      args:
        - while true; do echo -en '\n'; printf UNCHANGED_REFERENCE=$UNCHANGED_REFERENCE'\n'; printf SERVICE_ADDRESS=$SERVICE_ADDRESS'\n';printf ESCAPED_REFERENCE=$ESCAPED_REFERENCE'\n'; sleep 30; done;
      command:
        - sh
        - -c
      image: busybox
      env:
        - name: SERVICE_PORT
          value: "80"
        - name: SERVICE_IP
          value: "172.17.0.1"
        - name: UNCHANGED_REFERENCE
          value: "$(PROTOCOL)://$(SERVICE_IP):$(SERVICE_PORT)"
        - name: PROTOCOL
          value: "https"
        - name: SERVICE_ADDRESS
          value: "$(PROTOCOL)://$(SERVICE_IP):$(SERVICE_PORT)"
        - name: ESCAPED_REFERENCE
          value: "$$(PROTOCOL)://$(SERVICE_IP):$(SERVICE_PORT)"
```

Link to this example is [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-interdependent-environment-variables/#define-an-environment-dependent-variable-for-a-container)